# I am trying to use mysql with django but run into a problem when using pip to install mysqlclient

Tags: python, django, pip

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Django: >3

Python: 3.8

Full log: https://pastebin.com/B5YvNyBY

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

[...]

```
 unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
```

Comment: before installing that do this `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+unable+to+execute+%27x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc%27%3A+No+such+file+or+directory